# How can I exclude brs in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this pattern to make urls clickable, now in my text there are `<br />` and `<BR />`, if a link is followed by a br, the pattern include `<br />` and `<BR />` in the link, how can I exclude them in this pattern:

```
replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
```

This is the code that uses the pattern:

```
replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
```

Comment: You don't show the code that uses that pattern, but I tried it out with some simple code of my own and didn't have any problem with br elements: http://jsfiddle.net/mdm8r/ (for me - testing in Chrome - the br elements ended up after the link, i.e., after the closing `</a>` that my JS added). Given that your pattern shouldn't match on `<` I don't see how it could include a trailing br element...

Comment: Me neither: [http://regexr.com?34851](http://regexr.com?34851)

Comment: Still not: [http://regexr.com?34854](http://regexr.com?34854). Could you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with an example that illustrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**RegEx pattern**

```
(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])(?:<[bB][rR]\s?\/?>)*
```

**Replace pattern**

```
<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>
```

**Input**

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com<br>
http://www.stackoverflow.com<br/>
http://www.stackoverflow.com<br />
http://www.stackoverflow.com<BR>
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com<BR/>
http://www.stackoverflow.com<BR />
```

Here's a link: http://regexr.com?3485d

The regex will check if there is a (optional) br-tag. If none it will just match the normal url.

Comment: I thought OP wanted to *ignore* `<br/>`

Comment: Check the result in the link, it will be ignored in the result

Comment: No, I thought OP wanted to "exclude them in the pattern", but I think you're right. I think maybe OP wants to *include* then in the pattern so as to remove them from the replacement.